# How to get sign in with the ajax get request to MS?

Tags: ajax, microsoft-graph-api

I'd like to use MS Graph REST  API, I use an ajax get request to sign in the user (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/rest). How should I do that? I get the response just don't know how it'll popup.

This is the sample code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<app ID>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost/myapp%2F&response_type=code&state=1234&scope=mail.read",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function(response){
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to redirect the user to that signin page, not just sending a GET request to it. The user is shown a consent screen where they can review the permissions your app is requesting.

Using an auth library is significantly easier than manually handling the redirect to login.microsoftonline.com. There's a guide for authenticating to Graph with MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-javascriptspa

MSAL will help parse the response after the user has consented and is redirected back to your app